# What does the % 100 do after IP address in Self IP list on F5 load balancer

Tags: networking, load-balancing, f5

192.168.1.100%100

What does the percent sign and the 100 do following the IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means it's about the route domain number 100. To learn what are route domains, and why/how to use them, please read the [F5 doc](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/tmos-ip-routing-administration-11-2-0/2.html).